Question about glm family in R
When using glm() in R, is family = "binomial" the same as family = binomial? Are they interchangeable and producing the same results? I am looking at a binary classification problem.

The two commands glm(..., family="binomial") (1) and glm(... , family=binomial) (2) are the same (they will always give the same results).
You can see this from the R code of glm on lines 7-8:
  7:  if (is.character(family)) 
  8:    family <- get(family, mode = "function", envir = parent.frame())
  9:  if (is.function(family)) 
  10:   family <- family()

Version (1) specifies the family as a character string, which gets converted to a function using get(). This is now in the same form as version (2).
is.function(binomial)
[1] TRUE

is.function(get("binomial", mode = "function", envir = parent.frame()))
[1] TRUE


Thank you for providing such a detailed answer!

I get the same results when I quote as when I do not. However, that is only if I use the default link function (logistic regression). If I want to run a probit regression, my typical line of code would use glm(y ~ ., family = binomial(link = 'probit')). If I quote the entire family, I get an error: glm(y ~ ., family = "binomial(link = 'probit')"). When I just quote the binomial piece, glm(y ~ ., family = "binomial"(link = 'probit')), however, I get the same result.
I don't quote the family name when I run GLMs.

Okay, I didn't know about probit case. I am usually just using logistic regression lol
